# My UI is not updating with latest data after react-query mutation

Tags: reactjs

I have a form modal that adds new contact data to my database, but my UI does not update after adding the new data until I refresh my page.

My code

contact.tsx  // file responsible for fetch

```
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';

const fetchContact = async () => {
  const { data } = await http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/contact/create');
  return {
    data: data,
  };
};

const useContactQuery = () => {
  return useQuery(['http://localhost:5000/api/contact/create'], fetchContact);
};

export { useContactQuery, fetchContact };
```

//file responsible for mutation

```
export interface ContactFormValues {
    title: string;
    number: string;
  }
async function addContact(data: ContactFormValues) {
    const { data: response } = await http.post(API_URL + '/contact/create', data);
    return response.data;
}

export const useContactMutation = (closeModal: any) => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient()

  return useMutation((input: ContactFormValues) => addContact(input), {
    onSuccess: (data) => {
        const message = "Contact Added Successfuly"
        alert(message)
        closeModal();
    },
    onError: (data) => {
        alert(data + ' there was an error');
    },
  });
};
```

Contact Page // file responsible for displaying contact

```
import { useContactQuery } from '@framework/contact/contact';
import ContactBox from './contact-content';

const ContactPage: React.FC = () => {
  let { data, isLoading } = useContactQuery();
  return !isLoading ? (
    <div>
          <ContactBox items={data} />
        </div>
  ) : (
    <div>Loading...</div>
  );
};

export default ContactPage;
```

Contact page component

```
const ContactBox: React.FC<{ items?: any }> = ({ items: { data } }) => {
  let [contactData, setContactData] = useState(data);
  const { openModal } = useModalAction();
  function handlePopupView(item: any) {
    openModal('PHONE_NUMBER', item);
  }
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(data[0]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <RadioGroup
          value={selected}
          onChange={setSelected}
        >
          {contactData?.map((item: any, index: any) => (
            <RadioGroup.Option
              key={index}
              value={item}
            >
              <RadioGroup.Label as="h2" className="font-semibold mb-2">
                {item?.title}
              </RadioGroup.Label>
              <RadioGroup.Description as="div" className="opacity-70">
                {item?.number}
              </RadioGroup.Description>
              <div className="flex absolute end-3 top-3 z-30 lg:opacity-0 transition-all address__actions">
                <button
                  onClick={() => handlePopupView(item)}
                >
                  <TiPencil />
                </button>
              </div>
            </RadioGroup.Option>
          ))}
          <button
            onClick={handlePopupView}
          >
            <AiOutlinePlus size={18} className="me-2" />
            {t('text-add-phone-number')}
          </button>
        </RadioGroup>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ContactBox;
```

File responsible for adding contact

```
const AddContactForm: React.FC = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [number, setNumber] = useState('');

  const { closeModal } = useModalAction();

  const { mutate: addContact, isLoading } = useContactMutation(closeModal);

  function onSubmit(values: ContactFormValues) {
    addContact(values);
  }


  return (
    <div className="w-full md:w-[510px] mx-auto p-5 sm:p-8 bg-skin-fill rounded-md">
      <CloseButton onClick={closeModal} />
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} >
        <div className="mb-6">
          <Input
            value={title}
            onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-6">
          <Input
           value={number}
            onChange={(e) => setNumber(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <Button className="h-11 md:h-12 w-full mt-1.5" type="submit" disabled={isLoading}>
          {'Save Number'}
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddContactForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

When mutation is completed, you need to use `invalidateQueries` to invalidate the query, it will refetch the data.

```
export const useContactMutation = (closeModal: any) => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient()

  return useMutation((input: ContactFormValues) => addContact(input), {
    onSuccess: (data) => {
        queryClient.invalidateQueries('http://localhost:5000/api/contact/create');
        const message = "Contact Added Successfuly"
        alert(message);
        closeModal();
    },
    onError: (data) => {
        alert(data + ' there was an error');
    },
  });
};
```

Comment: Still not updating, until I refresh the page

Comment: How did you solve this ?